# issues with window.print() on apple devices

Tags: javascript

i have a page that uses a function to send the contents of a `<div>` to the print dialogue.
this works fine on Chrome on windows, Chome and Firefox on android devices.
however on apple devices it seems to ignore the `<div>` restriction and proceeds to offer the complete page to the print dialogue.

the user presses this button on the page

```
<input class="loginbutton" type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="PRINT" />
```

and the script is

```
<script>
    
    function printDiv(divName) {
         var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
         var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    
         document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    
         window.print();
    
         document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
    
</script>
```

all the content that should be presented is inside the `printableArea` section, however Safari is including content that is outside of that div. i can only assume it's a wekbit issue as the issue isn't apparent on any non-apple devices.

anyone any ideas how to get webkit browsers to play ball?

Comment: I think, because of how the event loop works, you have to call `print()` after the document has been repainted. Use `requestAnimationFrame` to schedule the call.

Comment: is that specific to webkit though? as there are no issues on any browser on non-apple devices

Comment: I honestly am not even sure that that is the fix. It may be though, you should try it. Just do `window.requestAnimationFrame(() => window.print())` instead of `window.print()`

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine yep that didn't work, and it also broke it on non apple devices too.

Comment: It's crazy to do your print styling like this. You are probably running into a desynchronisation issue. What you _should_ do is simply define hiding and showing of information using CSS;s media queries: `@media print {}`, which will work and correctly display and has worked for me on all devices (a bit hit and miss which css page break options are available but thats not important here)

Comment: @somethinghere oh right, i'd not considered doing it that way as this method did seem to work until someone with an apple device threw a spanner in the works.

basically it's a basic html form they complete, they then view the completed submitted form with a button to the allow them to either print it to a printer or save as PDF.